# Python dictionaries, find similarities

Tags: python, templates, dictionary, templating

I have a python dictionary with a thousand items.  Each item is, itself, a dictionary.  I'm looking for a clean and elegant way to parse through each item, and find & create templates.

Here's a simplified example of the individual dictionaries' structure:

```
{'id': 1,
 'template': None,
 'height': 80,
 'width': 120,
 'length': 75,
 'weight': 100}
```

From this, I want to pass through once, and if, 500 of the 1000 share the same height and width, determine that, so I can build a template off that data, and assign the template id to 'template'.  I can build a gigantic reference hash, but I'm hoping there's a cleaner more elegant way to accomplish this.

The actual data includes closer to 30 keys, of which a small subset need to be excluded from the template checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@eumiro had an excellent core idea, namely that of using `itertools.groupby()` to arrange the items with common values together in batches. However besides neglecting to sort things first using the same key function as @Jochen Ritzel pointed-out (and is also mentioned in the documentation), he also didn't address the several other things you mentioned wanting to do.

Below is a more complete and somewhat longer answer. It determines the templates and assigns them in one pass thought the dict-of-dicts. To do this, after first creating a sorted list of items, it uses `groupby()` to batch them, and if there are enough in each group, creates a template and assigns its ID to each member.

```
inventory = {
    'item1': {'id': 1, 'template': None, 'height': 80, 'width': 120, 'length': 75, 'weight': 100},
    'item2': {'id': 2, 'template': None, 'height': 30, 'width': 40,  'length': 20, 'weight': 20},
    'item3': {'id': 3, 'template': None, 'height': 80, 'width': 100, 'length': 96, 'weight': 150},
    'item4': {'id': 4, 'template': None, 'height': 30, 'width': 40,  'length': 60, 'weight': 75},
    'item5': {'id': 5, 'template': None, 'height': 80, 'width': 100, 'length': 36, 'weight': 33}
}

import itertools as itools

def print_inventory():
    print 'inventory:'
    for key in sorted(inventory.iterkeys()):
        print '  {}: {}'.format(key, inventory[key])

print "-- BEFORE --"
print_inventory()

THRESHOLD = 2
ALLKEYS = ['template', 'height', 'width', 'length', 'weight']
EXCLUDEDKEYS = ['template', 'length', 'weight']
INCLUDEDKEYS = [key for key in ALLKEYS if key not in EXCLUDEDKEYS]

# determines which keys make up a template
sortby = lambda item, keys=INCLUDEDKEYS: tuple(item[key] for key in keys)

templates = {}
templateID = 0
sortedinventory = sorted(inventory.itervalues(), key=sortby)
for templatetuple, similariter in itools.groupby(sortedinventory, sortby):
    similaritems = list(similariter)
    if len(similaritems) >= THRESHOLD:
        # create and assign a template
        templateID += 1
        templates[templateID] = templatetuple # tuple of values of INCLUDEDKEYS
        for item in similaritems:
            item['template'] = templateID
print
print "-- AFTER --"
print_inventory()
print
print 'templates:', templates
print
```

When I run it, the following is the output:

```
-- BEFORE --
inventory:
  item1: {'weight': 100, 'height': 80, 'width': 120, 'length': 75, 'template': None, 'id': 1}
  item2: {'weight': 20, 'height': 30, 'width': 40, 'length': 20, 'template': None, 'id': 2}
  item3: {'weight': 150, 'height': 80, 'width': 100, 'length': 96, 'template': None, 'id': 3}
  item4: {'weight': 75, 'height': 30, 'width': 40, 'length': 60, 'template': None, 'id': 4}
  item5: {'weight': 33, 'height': 80, 'width': 100, 'length': 36, 'template': None, 'id': 5}

-- AFTER --
inventory:
  item1: {'weight': 100, 'height': 80, 'width': 120, 'length': 75, 'template': None, 'id': 1}
  item2: {'weight': 20, 'height': 30, 'width': 40, 'length': 20, 'template': 1, 'id': 2}
  item3: {'weight': 150, 'height': 80, 'width': 100, 'length': 96, 'template': 2, 'id': 3}
  item4: {'weight': 75, 'height': 30, 'width': 40, 'length': 60, 'template': 1, 'id': 4}
  item5: {'weight': 33, 'height': 80, 'width': 100, 'length': 36, 'template': 2, 'id': 5}

templates: {1: (30, 40), 2: (80, 100)}
```

Comment: Excellent.  I was wrapping up some proof of concept code based on the first response, but your answer resolves some of the issues I was running across.  Thanks.  Love this place.

Answer (score 3):

Given dict of dicts `items`:

```
import itertools as it

for (height, width), itemIter in it.groupby (items.values(), lambda x: (x['height'], x['width'])):
    # in list(itemIter) you will find all items with dimensions (height, width)
```

Comment: It needs a round of sorting before groupby, because groupby will only group consecutive items with the same key.